# I am having trouble executing the code on the raspberry pi to read from the MCP3002 ADC

Tags: python, pi-2, script, analog-to-digital

Hi I am writing a python script to code the raspberry pi to read from the MCP3002 ADC. This is the code that I typed in onto the raspberry pi nano script

```
import spidev   
import time

def readAnalog(device = 0,channel = 0):
    assert device in (1, 0)
    assert channel in (1, 0)
    #open spi
    spi = spidev.SpiDev()
    spi.open(0, device)
    """
    Protocol start bit (S), sql/diff (D), odd/sign (C), MSBF (M)
    Use leading zero for more stable clock cycle
    0000 000S DCM0 0000 0000 0000
    Sending 3 8bit packages so xpi.xfer2 will return the same amount.
    start bit = 1
    sql/diff = 1 SINGLE ENDED MODE  (2 channel mode) 
    odd/sign = channel 0/1
    MSBF = 0
    """
    command = [1, (2 + channel) << 6, 0]
    #2 + channel shifted 6 to left
    #10 or 11 << 6 = 1000 0000 or 1100 0000
    reply = spi.xfer2(command)
    """
    Parse right bits from 24 bit package (3*8bit)
    We need only data from last 2 bytes.
    And there we can discard last two bits to get 10 bit value 
    as MCP3002 resolution is 10bits
    Discard reply[0] byte and start from reply[1] where our data starts
    """ 
    value = reply[1] & 31   
    #31 = 0001 1111 with & operation makes sure that we have all data from XXXX DDDD and nothing more. 0001 is for signed in next operation.
    value = value << 6  #Move to left to make room for next piece of data.
    #000D DDDD << 6 = 0DDD DD00 0000
    #Now we get the last of data from reply[2]
    value = value + (reply[2] >> 2)
    #Here we discard last to bits
    #DDDD DDXXX >> 2 = 00DD DDDD
    #0DDD DD00 0000 + 00DD DDDD = 0DDD DDDD DDDD
    spi.close()
    return value


def main():
    #read channel 0 on device 0
    value = readAnalog(0, 0)
    print value
    time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

but when I execute this code on the terminal it wouldn't work

[image]

All the connection that I have done are the same within this image, the only difference is I just have to substitute the potentiometer for the Infrared Distance Sensor

[image]

So what would be the right code for the raspberry pi to read from the MCP3002 ADC

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line as the first of your Python script.

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

This tells the system that the script should be executed by the Python interpreter.

At the moment the shell thinks the script is a list of shell commands and is getting confused.

Comment: I tried that but I'm still getting errors when I execute the script

Comment: If you are getting the same error I am at a loss.